# how to draw a constant line in a javaFX scatter chart

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

I'm new to JavaFX and implemented a scatter chart with various data series. That works well so far, but I want to highlight the data in a specific area as these are ok and all outside the area are bad. so my plan is to draw two lines in the chart, for example one at y=80 and one at y=120. is there a comfortable way to accomplish this? I wanted to avoid drawing the lines with a LineBuilder or so.

Comment: I am also looking for similar solution for one of the applications in javafx. JoeHut have you got any solution to this questions

Comment: @kleopatra was so kind to answer my other question which was  essentially the same. Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232931/adding-a-line-in-a-javafx-chart